# How did Cygwin g++ resolve it?

Tags: g++, cygwin, poco

I am puzzled how a mere `g++ -o testpoco testpoco.cpp -lPocoFoundation` was able to compile successfully in my `Cygwin` environment. The complete C++ code is below:

```
#include <Poco/File.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Poco::File f("/tmp/test.log");
    if (f.exists()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I installed the cygwin Poco development headers and libraries and I verified they are in:

- /usr/include/Poco/ (the header files)
- /usr/lib/ (the libraries)

But without specifying those include and library path in `g++` how did it was able to compile and produce the exe? I checked the output of `g++ -v` and did not see any routes to `Poco`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has default search paths for include files and for libraries. (Actually the latter applies to the linker, not the compiler, but the `g++` command invokes both.)

`/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` are in those default search paths.

You specified `#include <Poco/File.h>`, so the compiler found `/usr/include/Poco/File.h`.

You specified `-lPocoFoundation`, so the linker found `/usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.dll.a`, the file that contains the code implementing the PocoFoundation library under Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

> I checked the output of `g++ -v` and did not see any routes to Poco

The command `g++ -v` will just print out some version information about GCC, and how it was configured. Adding the `-v` option to your real commands used for compiling and/or linking will show the search paths for headers and libraries.

In other words, instead of just `g++ -v` you should try:

```
g++ -o testpoco testpoco.cpp -lPocoFoundation -v
```

This will show the search paths that Keith Thompson refers to in his answer.